# How to fix USDZ model that are too dark in AR Quick look

Tags: converters, usdz

I'm trying to convert an obj model to usdz but the model looks too dark when viewing in AR Quick Look on iPhone.

To convert the model I'm running.

```
xcrun usdz_converter Kudde_v03/Kudde_v03.obj ./Kudde_flower_2048.usdz -color_map Final_test_1/Textures/2048/Kudde_2048_flower_lagoon_color_map.png -normal_map Final_test_1/Textures/2048/Kudde_2048_normal_map.png -v
```

The model is converted fine and looks ok in Quick Look on my mac but when I look at it in Quick Look on my iPhone the model is too dark.
If I open the obj file in XCode and SceneKit the model also looks fine after applying the color map to the diffuse option.

It's like the lighting is all wrong in Quick look on iPhone. The issue is there in both object mode and AR mode.

This is what i looks like on iPhone X Quick look https://ibb.co/MG69BVb   (The preview in the Files app looks fine)
and using quick look on my mac https://ibb.co/gM626Zf
Using Xcode https://ibb.co/zPgfr7f

Heres my verbose output.

```
usdz_converter  
Version: 1.009  

-v: Verbose output  


Primitives:  
  Transform: /Kudde_v03  
  Transform: /Kudde_v03/Geom  
  GeomMesh: /Kudde_v03/Geom/ZBrush_defualt_group  
  bound material: /Kudde_v03/Materials/default  
  Replacing material  
  unbind material: /Kudde_v03/Materials/default  
  Binding to material /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0  
  GeomScope: /Kudde_v03/Materials  
  ShadeMaterial: /Kudde_v03/Materials/default  
  ShadeMaterial: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/pbr  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/Primvar  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/color_map  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/normal_map  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/ao_map  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/emissive_map  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/metallic_map  
  ShadeShader: /Kudde_v03/Materials/StingrayPBS_0/roughness_map
```

I've tried with a few different obj models and textures and the result is always the same. If I also add the color texture to the emissive_map the model is not dark any more but the colors are not right anymore.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an empty (black) metallic map while converting the model.

Comment: Does not seem to work as for now. Tried on different devices. All objects have some grey bias. Basically you can never have a white object and all other colors are multiplied by that grey bias.